# Access current document from Firefox extension browser action background script

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-action

I'm building a [toolbar button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Browser_action) extension for Firefox. In my background script, I need to access the `document` for the current tab when the toolbar button is clicked.

`window` in this context is the window for the extension, not for the current tab. Other functions like [`browser.tabs.getCurrent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/getCurrent) don't work in background scripts.

I know it is possible since other extensions have access to the current document (e.g. 1Password will identify and fill `input` elements.)

Note: All of the previous questions on SO about the same functionality from 2010, 2012, etc. are no longer value.

Comment: Content scripts can communicate with background scripts via messages https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_background_scripts

Comment: See https://vzurczak.wordpress.com/2017/11/23/getting-the-source-code-of-a-tab-from-a-web-extension/ for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the active tab in the current window you can use [tabs.query()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query)

e.g.:

```
browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true})
```

That is how to get the active tab.

Tab is separate from the content page (web page). In order to interact with the context page, you would need to inject your code into the page.

For example using [tabs.executeScript()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript)

As you are injecting into the active tab, there is no need to get the active tab separately any more, since `tabs.executeScript()` would inject into the active tab if `tabId` is omitted.

e.g.:

```
browser.tabs.executeScript({
  code: `console.log('location:', window.location.href);`
});
```

Comment: How would I then get the window/document of that tab?  I don't see anything in the docs or in their examples